# how to split the data that i extracted from a webpage and append each line to list?

Tags: python, data-extraction

as a part of my project i scraped data from webpage and removed all tags. now i want to split data at new lines and append it to a list , so that i can access any line of my scraped data  easily using list indexes.
here is my code in python

```
import requests
def getdata(f):
    s = requests.Session()
    login_data = {'username': f, 'x': '112', 'y': '38'
                  }
    headers = {'User-Agent':
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                   'Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36'}
    p = s.post('http://202.53.81.30/results/vr17r2ra/hno.php', data=login_data, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.content, 'html5lib')
    da = soup.find('table', attrs={'align': 'center', 'border': '1'})
    for row in da.findAll("tr"):
        so = BeautifulSoup(row.text, 'html.parser')
        text = so.get_text()
        text1 = text.rstrip()
        print(text1[1])
```

till `text = so.get_text()`  if we execute and use
`f = 198w1a0561`  to the getdata function  i get the whole data i scraped.

```
text1 = text.rstrip()
print(text1[1])
```

to solve it i did like this . but i am not able to access specific lines of the text using this?
instead this what should i do?
what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `BeautifulSoup` a second time for `so`. Rather you can run `row.find_all('th', {'align': 'CENTER'})` to get the relevant table rows. And you can use `text.strip()` to get the clean text. I've wrapped it up in a list comprehension:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getdata(f):
    s = requests.Session()
    login_data = {'username': f, 'x': '112', 'y': '38'
                  }
    headers = {'User-Agent':
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                   'Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36'}
    p = s.post('http://202.53.81.30/results/vr17r2ra/hno.php', data=login_data, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.content, 'html5lib')
    da = soup.find('table', attrs={'align': 'center', 'border': '1'})
    return list(filter(None, [[i.text.strip() for i in row.find_all('th', {'align': 'CENTER'})] for row in da.find_all('tr')]))
```

Output:

```
[['1', '17CH1202A', 'Ex', '10'], ['2', '17EC1204A', 'A+', '9'], ['3', '17MC1206B', 'Ex', '10'], ['4', '17MA1201', 'Ex', '10'], ['5', '17CS1203', 'Ex', '10'], ['6', '17ME1205', 'A', '8'], ['7', '17CH1251', 'Ex', '10'], ['8', '17CS1252', 'Ex', '10']]
```